# Derivative of “nestable”

Tags: adjectives, negation

I am asking in terms of mathematics. When one has a radical that can be simplified, it is denestable *(Google displays only one instance of this word usage, is it even correct?)* in a sense that it is possible to factor out a number from it.

How do I say the opposite? I mean, is a radical that can not be unnested **undenestable**/**indenestable**/**not denestable**? Provided that the adjective *denestable* is correct, what would be its opposite?

Comment: **fully denested**? Or as Robert Palmer might say, "Simply undenestible".

Comment: @TRomano  there's a special place in Hell reserved for people like you  :)

Comment: When in doubt, use "not X".  So "not denestable" is probably your safest bet.

Comment: "Undenestable" is correct and understandable, if not beautiful.  Remember, English is a language that has the word [antidisestablishmentarianism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antidisestablishmentarianism), so it is perfectly acceptable to keep tacking on suffixes and prefixes.

Comment: @Andrew:  That's odd, they told me it was S.R.O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My vote would be for

> *non*denestable

to mean is not denestable, in math *non* is often used in cases when *something* is not supposed to happen

> *non*integer numbers
>   *non*prime numbers
>   *non*divisible

whereas *un* gets used for something which is not done yet

> *un*differentiated equations